# Get the list of Jira issues linked to a given bitbucket branch

Tags: python, bitbucket, jira, jira-rest-api, bitbucket-api

We use the Jira - BitBucket integration.

Assuming I would like to query all Jira issues that are connected/linked to a **given** branch.
The branch could have a different name than the automatic one you get when you create a branch from a Jira issue. This means that when creating a branch from Jira issue, we rename it by adding new jira issue keys on top when needed. For sure the Branch is created within the Jira issue.

I would like to get the list of issues linked to a given branch. I need the list of issues related to a **given branch** not to a given **pull request**.